# Postgres query not returning any rows using the like operator

Tags: php, postgresql

I have the following query

`Select alpha_key,name,trading_as ,typeclient from client_details where upper(trading_as) like '%TEST\\''S LOGISTICS SERVICES%' order by name ;`

does not return any rows but

`Select alpha_key,name,trading_as ,typeclient from client_details where upper(trading_as) = 'TEST\\''S LOGISTICS SERVICES' order by name ;`

returns a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape twice the backslash because there are a double interpretation, one when analizing the string and another one when compare with `LIKE`.

So your request becomes:

```
Select alpha_key,name,trading_as ,typeclient 
from client_details 
where upper(trading_as) like '%TEST\\\\''S LOGISTICS SERVICES%' 
order by name ;
```